# Transpose linear indices of a 2D matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I want to efficiently transpose linear indices of my 2D matrix, and I struggle coming up with efficient code to do it (see below for my suboptimal solution). How can this be done as efficiently as possible (RAM doesn't matter, just speed)?

suppose we have a 2D matrix `a`:

```
a = [1:4;5:8;9:12;13:16;17:20]'

a =

     1     5     9    13    17
     2     6    10  ->14<-  18
     3    >7<   11    15    19
     4     8    12    16    20
```

now I have some indices, like `7` and `14`, that I would really like to have transposed, so that the index of `7` (3,2) becomes `12` (2,3) and `14` (4,2) becomes `9`(2,4).

```
>> a'

ans =

     1     6     11     16
     2     7    >12<    17
     3     8     13     18
     4   ->9<-   14     19
     5     10    15     20
```

Right now, I use something silly:

```
tmp = zeros(size(a));
tmp([7 14])=1; %mark linear indices as '1' in the matrix
tmp=tmp'; %transpose the whole matrix
solution = find(tmp);
%then some sorting...

solution =

      9
     12
```

(obviously, with `ind2sub` one can simply get the indices, then flip them. I'm looking for a more efficient solution where I can directly transform the indices, without the need of additional variables)

Comment: I found [this solution](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/467805-is-there-a-method-to-linear-index-to-a-transpose-matrix-without-taking-the-transpose) but didn't manage to implement it. Sorry if this has been asked before already, I really couldn't find.

Comment: I found the "`a'`" part confusing, since what you show below that is not actually `a'`.  Consider rewording your question

Comment: “I'm looking for a more efficient solution where I can directly transform the indices, without the need of additional variables.” Is this computation too slow? Is this really the bottleneck in your program? Or is it that you don’t want to pollute your namespace with the intermediate variables? This latter issue is solved by creating a function that does the computation.

Comment: @CrisLuengo the computation is just executed like 20000 times. Since the indices are shifted pseudorandomly every time and then this transformation happens, I wanted it to be as fast as possible. Reworking the code so the shift happens after the transformation would be more efficient, but I'm only thinking of this now (after a break and writing this question - apologies). Marked Luis Mendo's code as correct because it _can_ be put in a one-liner, and possibly is faster than using `row` and `col` variables 20000 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this does what you want:

```
sz = [4 5]; % size of original a
input_ind = [7 14]; % input linear indices
row_ind = mod(input_ind-1,sz(1))+1; % row indices from input linear indices
col_ind = floor((input_ind-1)/sz(1))+1; % column indices from input linear indices
output_ind = col_ind + (row_ind-1)*sz(2); % output linear indices, obtained using
    % col_ind as row indices, row_ind as column indices, and sz(2) instead of sz(1)
```

Comment: This would be easier implemented with `ind2sub` and `sub2ind`, which OP didn’t want to use for some weird reason...

Comment: `ind2sub` and `sub2ind` do incur some overhead, although probably small